# Generic try catch method ASYNC in .NET 5 and 6: state of the art?

Tags: c#, .net-5

what is the state of the art in .NET 5 or 6 to do a generic try / catch method?
What is the best practice in 5/6 .NET on this issue?

Use case:

I need one place to execute async methods in a try catch.
Dummy code:

```
private Task DoMyMethodeInTryCatch(MyMethod myMethodeAsParameter) 
{
            try
            {
                myMethodeAsParameter.Run();
            }
            catch (ExceptionHandlerOne e)
            {

            }
            catch (ExceptionHandlerTwo e)
            {

            }            
            catch (ExceptionHandlerTree e)
            {

            }
}
```

What I want to prevent is something line this:

```
private void Methode1()
{
            try
            {
                DoStuffOne();
            }
            catch (ExceptionHandlerOne e)
            {

            }
            catch (ExceptionHandlerTwo e)
            {

            }            
            catch (ExceptionHandlerTree e)
            {

            }
}

private void Methode2()
{
            try
            {
                DoStuffTwo();
            }
            catch (ExceptionHandlerOne e)
            {

            }
            catch (ExceptionHandlerTwo e)
            {

            }            
            catch (ExceptionHandlerTree e)
            {

            }
}
```

What I finally need is this:

```
private void DoStuff()
{
    await DoMyMethodeInTryCatch(DoStuffOne); // DoStuffOne run in a try catch block
    await DoMyMethodeInTryCatch(DoStuffTwo); // DoStuffTwo run in a try catch block
}
```

Comment: You want the try catch where you are awaiting the method calls. Otherwise, catch an AggregateException instead.

Comment: `async Task DoMyMethodeInTryCatch(Func<Task> myMethodeAsParameter) { try { await myMethodeAsParameter(); } catch... }`?

Answer (score 0):

If the set of `catch` blocks is fixed and doesn't depend on any variables/state inside the `try` block, you can create a method that executes an action in the `try` block:

```
async Task DoWork(Func<Task> a)
{
    try
    {
        await a();
    }
    catch (ExceptionHandlerOne e)
    { ... }
    catch (ExceptionHandlerTwo e)
    { ... }
    catch (ExceptionHandlerTree e)
    { ... }
}
```

which allows you to call DoWork similarly in your code

```
    await DoWork(DoStuffOne);
    await DoWork(DoStuffTwo);
```

If you want to get a return value, then you can add a DoWork that takes a generic parameter

```
async Task<T> DoWork<T>(Func<Task<T>> a)
{
    try
    {
        return await a();
    }

    // note, you will need to add return statements below if these catches don't throw

    catch (ExceptionHandlerOne e)
    { ... }
    catch (ExceptionHandlerTwo e)
    { ... }
    catch (ExceptionHandlerTree e)
    { ... }
}
```

If your set of catch blocks can vary, then I suggest catching just `Exception` and then choosing the appropriate exception handler from a dictionary of handlers perhaps (there are other ways, but let's show this way as a basis):

```
async Task DoWork(Func<Task> a, IDictionary<Type, Action<Exception>> exceptionHandlers)
{
    try
    {
        await a();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        // this itself has no error handling... just here as an idea...
        exceptionHandlers[e.GetType](e);
    }
}
```

You can get fancier to avoid casting exceptions inside the handlers (maybe use `dynamic`), but this is the gist of it.

Comment: Thanks Kit! This is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks for your answer!